# htaccess redirect to directory outside root directory

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to redirect image files to directory outside of root directory?

Directory structure

```
wamp\www\site\images\image.jpg
```

Redirect to

```
wamp\www\images\image.jpg
```

Using .htaccess something like.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ ../images/$1
```

Also if this can be done by any other means that will be good as well.

Comment: Not via .htaccess. You can do it with mod_alias at the VirtualHost level, but it would be a giant security risk for .htaccess.  `Alias /images C:\path\to\wamp\www\to\images`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski what is mod_alias any tutorial? and can I do that in shared server.

Comment: [Apache mod_alias docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)... You can only do it if you have access to the VirtualHost config in your server (which is uncommon on shared hosting).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for tutorial link. I need to check if I can do it in my server.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Hi can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219638/htaccess-switch-user-to-full-site-from-mobile-site-when-url-link-is-clicked if you have time.